# Prolog association list

Tags: dictionary, prolog, sicstus-prolog

I am writing a simple program safety checker in Prolog and I need a data structure to hold variable valuation. Since I want to detect when I am visiting same state again, this structure must support some reasonable comparison semantics, so I can store visited states in set.

`library(avl)` has convenient getter/setter interface.
The problem is, AVL holding the same mapping can take multiple forms.
Thus two identical states would be considered distinct if their AVL representation differs.

A structure holding mapping in ordered lists would be free of this problem. However, I can't find anything like that in Sicstus docs. Is there any standard structure that does what I need, or do I have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [ordered sets](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/sicstus/sicstus_20.html#SEC178) but in AVL you can always [convert AVLs to ordered lists](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.2/html/sicstus/lib_002davl.html) of key-valued pairs and then compare them.

Comment: I have seen ordered sets, but they don't allow operations such us finding a value for a given key (say you store Key-Val pairs; then ord_member(0-Val, Set) will not find value associated with Key=0). I'll go with the second solution, though it beats the purpose of using tree...

Comment: The behaviour of `ord_member` seems then a bit strange. Unfortunately I do not have SICStus installed but SWI behaves as expected: `?- ord_member(0-Val, [0-[1,2,3],1-[2,3,5],6-[5,3,5,4,21]]).` returns `Val = [1, 2, 3].`

Comment: Sicstus answers `no` to your example. It's `ord_member(+Key, +Set)` in docs, so I guess behavior is implementation dependent when Key is not fully instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for testing it with SICStus... One can, of course, implement `ord_member/2` himself...